# Reducing size of longtable

Tags: longtable

I would like to fit my table on one page with the title.

The code is:

```
       \documentclass[11p]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[margin=3cm, left=2cm, includefoot]{geometry}
        \usepackage{longtable}

    \section{table 1}
        \begin{document}
                \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
            \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
            \begin{longtable}{l*{3}{c}}
            \caption{{\b table 1 }}\\
\hline\hline\endfirsthead\hline\endhead\hline\endfoot\endlastfoot
                                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\
                                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{investments}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{investments}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{investments}\\
            \hline
            var0  &    0.000112\sym{++} &    0.000106\sym{++} &    0.000119\sym{+++}\\
                                &      (1.63)         &      (1.55)         &      (1.85)         \\
            [1em]
            var1    &       0.121\sym{+}  &       0.126\sym{+}  &       0.132\sym{++} \\
                                &      (1.33)         &      (1.38)         &      (1.46)         \\
            [1em]
            var2                 &     0.00420         &     0.00353         &     0.00479         \\
                                &      (1.04)         &      (0.87)         &      (1.17)         \\
            [1em]
            var3                &   -0.000207         &                     &                     \\
                                &     (-0.31)         &                     &                     \\
            [1em]
            var4        &    0.000744         &    0.000951         &    0.000697         \\
                                &      (0.75)         &      (1.02)         &      (0.78)         \\
            [1em]
            var5   &  -0.0000825         &   -0.000217         &   -0.000199         \\
                                &     (-0.04)         &     (-0.10)         &     (-0.10)         \\
            [1em]
            var6                  &    -0.00194         &    -0.00171         &                     \\
                                &     (-0.65)         &     (-0.56)         &                     \\
            [1em]
            var7 &    0.000311         &    0.000233         &    0.000264         \\
                                &      (0.41)         &      (0.30)         &      (0.37)         \\
            [1em]
            var8           &                     &                     &    -0.00713         \\
                                &                     &                     &     (-0.80)         \\
            [1em]
            var9          &                     &                     &     -0.0175\sym{+++}\\
                                &                     &                     &     (-1.68)         \\
            [1em]
            var10           &                     &                     &     -0.0176         \\
                                &                     &                     &     (-1.21)         \\
            [1em]
            Constant            &     0.00633         &    -0.00603         &    -0.00771         \\
                                &      (0.08)         &     (-0.10)         &     (-0.13)         \\
            \hline
            Observations        &         111         &         111         &         111         \\
            \(R^{2}\)           &                     &                     &                     \\
            \hline\hline
            \multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
            \multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{+} \(p<0.2\), \sym{++} \(p<.15\), \sym{+++} \(p<0.1\), \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.02\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
            \end{longtable}
            \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

I tried using `\resize`, but I did not manage to make it work.

Comment: Could you please make your code a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by completing your code with the documentclass, the necessary packages and margin settings if used? Also, why do you use a `longtable` if you want your table to fit onto a single page?

Comment: @leandriis Sorry for that, I just corrected the code. I used longtable because i downloaded it directly from STATA, and that was the one they used. Should i change that?

Comment: Thank your for updating your example. `longtable` is intended to split tables that are too long to fit onto one page over several pages. If you want your table to fit on one page, you simply don't need it. (Apart from that, a `longtable` environment is not intended to be used inside a `table` environment.) With that in mind, your table is not too large for a page, so it should fit. What I unfortnately still don't understand is the part about the title in your question, as there is not title in the MWE.

Comment: never use `longtable` inside a `table`. It seems you do not want longtable at all, and just use a normal `tabular`

Comment: @leandriis I forgot to add that part, when I was talking about the title I was referring to the `\section{}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am sorry, I am still a beginner with Latex. Should I just remove the `longtable` and insert `tabular`? Because i tried to do so, but it give me an error.

Answer (score 1):

try, maybe you liked:

```
\documentclass[11p]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm, left=2cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn, threeparttable}      % new
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}                   % new, for numbers aligning
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}           % new, handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{d{3.9}}}
    \toprule
        &   \mc{(1)}            &   \mc{(2)}            &   \mc{(3)}            \\
        &   \mc{investments}    &   \mc{investments}    &   \mc{investments}    \\
    \midrule
var0    &    0.000112\tnote{++} &   0.000106\tnote{++}  &   0.000119\tnote{+++} \\
        &   (1.63)              &   (1.55)              &   (1.85)              \\
    \addlinespace
var1    &   0.121\tnote{+}      &   0.126\tnote{+}      &   0.132\tnote{++}     \\
        &   (1.33)              &   (1.38)              &   (1.46)              \\
    \addlinespace
var2    &   0.00420             &   0.00353             &   0.00479             \\
        &   (1.04)              &   (0.87)              &   (1.17)              \\
    \addlinespace
var3    &   -0.000207           &                       &                       \\
        &   (-0.31)             &                       &                       \\
    \addlinespace
var4    &   0.000744            &   0.000951            &   0.000697            \\
        &   (0.75)              &   (1.02)              &   (0.78)              \\
    \addlinespace
var5    &  -0.0000825           &   -0.000217           &   -0.000199           \\
        &   (-0.04)             &   (-0.10)             &   (-0.10)             \\
    \addlinespace
var6    &   -0.00194            &   -0.00171            &                       \\
        &   (-0.65)             &   (-0.56)             &                       \\
    \addlinespace
var7    &   0.000311            &   0.000233            &   0.000264            \\
        &   (0.41)              &   (0.30)              &   (0.37)              \\
    \addlinespace
var8    &                       &                       &   -0.00713            \\
        &                       &                       &   (-0.80)             \\
     \addlinespace
var9    &                       &                       &   -0.0175\tnote{+++}  \\
        &                       &                       &   (-1.68)             \\
    \addlinespace
var10   &                       &                       &   -0.0176             \\
        &                       &                       &   (-1.21)             \\
    \addlinespace
Constant    &   0.00633         &   -0.00603            &   -0.00771            \\
            &   (0.08)          &   (-0.10)             &   (-0.13)             \\
    \addlinespace
Observations    &   \mc{111}    &   \mc{111}            &   \mc{111}            \\
    \(R^{2}\)   &               &                       &                       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize
    \item[] statistics in parentheses

    \item[+]    \(p<0.2\),
    \item[++]   \(p<.15\),
    \item[+++]  \(p<0.1\).

    \item[*]    \(p<0.05\),
    \item[**]   \(p<0.02\),
    \item[***]  \(p<0.01\).
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

above mwe gives:

[image]

i redesign your table a little bit :-):

- numbers are aligned at decimal points. for this i used `dcolumn` package
- instead `\hline` i use rules `toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule` from the package `booktabs`. to my taste with this table look nices
- for table notes i use `tablenotes` environment from the package `threeparttable`
- instead `\\[1em]` if for row's pairs separating is used `\addlinespace` from the package `booktabs`

**edit:** 
it is not clear what you mean with "to fit my table on one page with the title". is this section title, table caption? if your real table is not larger than shown, then there is enough space on the page for the title of the section and some lines of text. to show this i add section title to my code.